# Converting a formula into vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet Evaluation. In the sheet, I have to look for the three columns S, T, and U.

If the column S contains invalid and if the column T and U are both filled, then I need to filter the complete row.

For this, I tried the below code. The code works fine for me. but for my other colleagues, the filter does not work according to the condition.

Column Z is considered as an helper column that marks true, or false depending on the condition. If both the columns T and U are filled and S is invalid , then it marks as false, and the rest as true

I have used option explicit above all the modules.

Can anyone suggest, how I can overcome this ? Can any one help me to code , without using the formula

```
Sub fc()
Dim totalrows As Long
Dim sformula

totalrows = Range("A5").End(xlDown).Row
  With Sheets("Evaluation").Range("Z5:Z" & totalrows)
  ' if the S5 is not equal to invalid and any one of the column T and U are filled, then activate autofilter
    sformula = "=AND(S5<>""Invalid"",OR(ISBLANK(T5),ISBLANK(U5)))"
     .Formula = sformula
    .AutoFilter 26, True
    .Value = .Value
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Just move the .Value = .Value above the autofilter and check.

Comment: @Sixthsense is there any other way ? I tried to work with it

Answer (score 2):

I just tried it out, and according to my experience there, the following should work:

```
Sub fc()
Dim totalrows As Long, sformula AS String
sformula = "=AND(S5<>""Invalid"",OR(ISBLANK(T5),ISBLANK(U5)))"

totalrows = Range("A5").End(xlDown).Row
  With Sheets("Evaluation").Range("Z5:Z" & totalrows)
    .Formula = sformula
    .AutoFilter 1, True ' take the first column of the current range
  End With
End Sub
```

In your version you used `.AutoFilter 26, True` which *would* work, had you applied it to the range `[a1:z<no of rows>]`, but since you are working on the range `[z1:z<no of rows>]` you only *have* one column in your range.

I also don't know what you are trying to achieve with `.value = .value`. As far as I can see, this would only replace the current value with the current value, i. e. do nothing useful, or am I missing something?

Comment: I will try this and get back to you. could you provide me the reason behind this change, It would be helpful

Comment: By applying the autofllter in the range in column 1, everything has been filtered,

Comment: Well, not in my example: The `1` was interpreted in a relative way, looking at column `z`. At least in my Excel sheet. When I try to use a number greater than 1 I get `Run tim error 1004: AutoFilter method of Range class failed`. So I *can* only use `.AutoFilter 1, True`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub fc()
Dim totalrows As Long, sformula As String

totalrows = Range("A5").End(xlDown).Row
sformula = "=AND(S5<>""Invalid"",OR(ISBLANK(T5),ISBLANK(U5)))"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheets("Evaluation").Range("Z5:Z" & totalrows)
     .Formula = sformula
     .Calculate
     DoEvents
     .Value = .Value
    .AutoFilter 26, True
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't understand, your code works completely fine with my machine. but it does not work with my friends laptop. we both use the same EXcel version 2013. What could be the reason ? Could you please help me to figure out the issue